# Firebase HTTP Trigger Cloud Function to change users' values in realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

So I have written code which should change a certain value in the database. I would use cron-jobs to trigger it in every 24h, but there is something wrong with my code.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.resetPicksStatus = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  .ref('/users/{userId}')
  .onWrite(event => {
    const status = event.data.val()
    if (status.resetted) {
        return true
    }
    console.log("Resetting status for " + event.paramas.userId)
    status.resetted = true
    status.picksDone = resetToNil(status.picksDone)
    return event.data.ref.set(status)
  })
})

  function resetToNil(s) {
    var resetValue = s
    resetValue = resetValue.replace(/\b1\b/ig, "0")
    return resetValue
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "but there is something wrong with my code"? Does the function not work or does the cron job not fire. If the first, what errors do you get?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're trying to put a Realtime Database trigger inside your HTTP trigger, which won't have the outcome you're looking for. Instead of using a database trigger, use the Firebase Admin SDK to access the database from within the HTTP trigger.

In your code, add

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const ref = admin.database().ref();
```

And use ref to access the database.

Check out the Admin SDK documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/).

[Here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples) are some samples of Cloud Functions, some of which show the Admin SDK.

[Here's a video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=3lzEgwiSs-M) showing how to use the Admin SDK

[Here's a video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=CbE2PzvAMxA) on timing Cloud Functions